# ADB on Linux Mint 17.1 doesn't recognize Zenfone 5 with Android Kitkat 4.4.2

Tags: android, linux, adb, smartphone

As described in the title, ADB v4.2.2 in Linux Mint 17.1 KDE with latest updates doesn't recognize my Zenfone 5 A501 with Android Kitkat 4.4.2 with latest updates.
When I tried:

> adb devices

the output is always

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

despite I plugged/unplugged.
My laptop didn't have Windows so I can't check.
Please help me. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: your system does recognize your device. you just did not configure permissions to access the device. read http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-most-comprehensive-write-up-on-how.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do this settings ([Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)):

If you're developing on Ubuntu Linux, you need to add a udev rules file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development. In the rules file, each device manufacturer is identified by a unique vendor ID, as specified by the `ATTR{idVendor}` property. For a list of vendor IDs, see [USB Vendor IDs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#VendorIds), below.

To set up device detection on Ubuntu Linux: Log in as root and create this file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`. Use this format to add each vendor to the file:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

In this example, the **vendor ID** is for **ASUS**. The MODE assignment specifies read/write permissions, and GROUP defines which Unix group owns the device node. Note: The rule syntax may vary slightly depending on your environment. Consult the udev documentation for your system as needed. For an overview of rule syntax, see this guide to writing udev rules.

Now execute:

```
chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Answer (score -1):

adb work in `linux zenfone 5`, make sure **usb debugging option is active** in developer options.
`fastboot` don't recognize the device, to work follow the steps above:

1. download the fastboot binary compiled to chipset intel in http://www.mediafire.com/download/pbr4b2x2ig9b2m5/fastboot
2. put binary in `/usr/bin/`
3. set **permissions** if necessary (`sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/fastboot`)
4. enjoy `adb` and `fastboot` working in `linux`.
5. credits for `fastboot binary` to `TK`. (https://software.intel.com/en-us/user/1068033)